# Wordpress remove_filter not working

Tags: filters

The site date has changed from Gregorian date to Jalali with a plugin, and that's good.

```
if (get_locale() == 'fa_IR')  {
add_filter('wp_date', 'wpp_fix_i18n', 10, 4);
}
```

And now I want the date of the site to change to Jalali only when the language of the site is Persian (fa_IR).
And I added this code but it does not work.

```
if (get_locale() != 'fa_IR')  {
remove_filter('wp_date', 'wpp_fix_i18n', 10, 4);
}
```

Comment: Isn’t that what your first block of code does?

Comment: The two parts are different, add_filter and remove_filter

Comment: Your first bit of code only adds that filter for Persian, so I don’t understand why you need remove_filter at all.

Comment: That's a good thing
But by add first bit of code, all dates will be changed in all languages.
Maybe get_locale() always is equal to WPLANG.
And the WPLANG selected in the WordPress admin settings is always fa_IR.
And I do the language switch with the user side translator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "remove_filter" function only accepts 3 params: the hook name ("wp_date"), the callback function ("wpp_fix_i18n") and the priority (10). You are using 4 params.

I'm sure your problem is related with the execution lifecycle. You are trying to remove a filter before it was created.

To solve it, wrap your function inside init hook in your theme functions.php to ensure plugin is loaded (and filter is added):

```
function mytheme_fix_date_issue () {
    if (get_locale() != 'fa_IR')  {
        remove_filter('wp_date', 'wpp_fix_i18n', 10);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'mytheme_fix_date_issue');
```